# Tool to make a DIFF between HTML tables?

Tags: html, diff

I am seeking a tool to make a DIFF between tables displayed in HTML tables - typically tables with identical layout, filled only with numbers, the numbers differing from on version to another.

Raw diff tool at the HTML level aren't readable enough for my purpose. I am rather seeking something in the spirit of [TableTools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2637) but with DIFF support.

Does anyone know a solution for that?

Comment: does the operating system matter?

Comment: Well, not really, as long it's Windows :-)

Comment: @akira: No it doesn't, they also have a Linux version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) is by far the best visual diff tool for Windows. It is not free, but not expensive. From the website: "Compare .csv data or HTML tables in a Data Compare session"

- http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=moreinfo_viewers
- http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=screenshot&shot=DataCompare